# python list with tuple iterate for existence and get the index

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have python list that has tuples, I want to check if the first element of the tuple in all tuples in the list, I manage to do that as follows:

```
x = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3)]
if 'a' in ([y[0] for y in x]):
    //how to get the index of the tuple that 'a' exist
```

What I want in the index of the tuple that 'a' as above example exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
next(i for i in xrange(0, len(x)) if x[i][0] == 'a')
```

Note that if `a` would not be found, you'll get `StopIteration` exception. You can also provide a default to have a value returned instead:

```
next((i for i in xrange(0, len(x)) if x[i][0] == 'd'), -1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> next(i for i in xrange(0, len(x)) if x[i][0] == 'a')
0
>>> next((i for i in xrange(0, len(x)) if x[i][0] == 'd'), -1)
-1
```

---

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) can also be used here to get the index value:

```
>>> next(i for i, (a, _) in enumerate(x) if a == 'a')
0
>>> next((i for i, (a, _) in enumerate(x) if a == 'd'), -1)
-1
```